# SignalR Undefined is not a function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundle, signalr

I have the following in my layout

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

[image: Scripts in my scripts folder]

and in the **Global.asax** `Application_Start()`

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

SignalR works fine but it's throwing an error

**Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

So it doesn't work well with bundles or is there something else?

Comment: Can you show the code for how you are building your `"~/Scripts/js"` bundle?

Comment: Everything is in the question. The first line builds a bundle from every script inside Scripts folder. That was the problem as i've stated in my answer.

Comment: Glad that you were able to get it working. If you want to learn more about creating and using bundles, please refer to http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously  the

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script
```

is not working and after some experiments i've solved it by moving signalr scripts to different folder (**Scripts/signalr**) and used the following in my _Layout.cshtml file.:

```
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/signalr/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/signalr/hubs")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `;` in signalr-x.x.x.js after 
`...{ n.signalR.version = "1.1.2" }(window.jQuery)`.

The result string is:

```
...{ n.signalR.version = "1.1.2" }(window.jQuery);
```